# iOS Files in Application Support Directory or Documents Directory deleted after update

Tags: ios, objective-c, filesystems, nsfilemanager

I have an iOS app where i copy a mp3 file from the bundle to a directory within Application Support Folder (Btw same thing happens if i use the Documents folder), and later user's download more mp3 files they are also stored there. Everything works fine until an update is published (or i install another instance using Xcode during dev), where the app says the files do not exist at the path. I have tried everything and i am stumped why do my files always get deleted after an update or overwrite install using Xcode.

Here is my code:

```
//folder being created here
NSString *libraryPath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Tracks"];

            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:libraryPath
                                      withIntermediateDirectories:YES
                                                       attributes:nil
                                                            error:&error];
            if (error != nil) {
                NSLog(@"error creating directory: %@", error);
            }
            //file about to be copied
            NSString *sourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Evening-Visualization-vph" ofType:@"mp3"];
            libraryPath = [libraryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Evening-Visualization-vph.mp3"];

            if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:sourcePath
                                                       toPath:libraryPath
                                                        error:&error]){
                NSLog(@"Error Copying File from Bundle to Library");
            }
            NSURL * fileURL;
            fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:libraryPath];
            //file being marked so its not backed up to iCloud
            if (![fileURL setResourceValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool: YES] forKey:NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error:nil]) {
                NSLog(@"Do not backup marked FAILED");
            }

            track.trackLocalPath = libraryPath;
```

The only solution i have left now is to manually check on each launch whether files exist at those path and mark my file list DB accordingly.

Comment: The files are not deleted, but the path to the folder does change - see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28653159/3985749).  Save only the path relative to the `NSApplicationSupportDirectory`, and then add it to the path for the `NSApplicationSupportDirectory` each time.

Comment: @pbasdf Thank You! This was the exact issue!

Comment: please add the comment as an answer and mark this question as "Answered"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode changes location of applications folder on build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28652894/xcode-changes-location-of-applications-folder-on-build)